# Chrome error with NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR DOM Exception 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, google-chrome

I have below code to insert a style into DOM (there is a use case for injecting style into DOM so please don't ask why or say to load the css in .css file).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var bmstyle = document.createElement('style');
    bmstyle.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    var styleStr = "#test-div {background:#FFF;border:2px solid #315300;";
    bmstyle.innerHTML = styleStr;
    document.body.appendChild(bmstyle);
}

</script>
```

If I run in Firefox, it works fine. But I got this error in Google Chrome:

```
Line bmstyle.innerHTML = styleStr;
Uncaught Error: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7
```

Does anyone have a fix? Thanks

Comment: Look like my problem is described here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3976#makechanges so I wonder if "is there a way to work around??" Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's because you are using `innerHTML` when everywhere else you are using XML syntax. Try:

```
bmstyle.nodeValue = styleStr;
```

Suggestion 2:

It might also be because you are trying to set the innerHTML of a an element not yet in the HTML DOM. If that's the case, my first suggestion should still hold up, or you can go with:

```
document.body.appendChild(bmstyle);
bmstyle.innerHTML = styleStr;
```

I'm not sure if you'd need a line inbetween to reclaim the element or if the bmstyle would still point to it.

Comment: I should mention that since the DOM in this case is an HTML DOM, it shouldn't matter. But Chrome may be pissy when you don't set up the DOM Element variable explicitly as HTML.

Comment: I used your suggestion 2 and it still has error. I used suggestion 1 with nodeValue, it has no error but the style tag has nothing in it (btw, I corrected to add } at the end). Should I insert in header instead and how?

Comment: When I use it, the console gimme: HierarchyRequestError, any idea?... the browser is IE

Answer (score 3):

Just a note for future reference... I'm using the following function to dynamically create CSS styles.  I found that using textContent worked the best.

This breaks on Safari

```
el.innerHTML = css.join('\n');
```

This breaks on FireFox

```
el.innerText = css.join('\n');
```

The following is my final code that works on both browsers.  IE not tested...

```
/**
* Write out stylesheets to the page.
* 
* @param {array} css
*/
function print_css(css) {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        el = document.createElement('style');

    el.type = 'text/css';
    el.textContent = css.join('\n');
    headTag.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Me too, I had this problem, try this one:

```
bmstyle.value = styleStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be because it's invalid to put `<style>` elements inside the body, but to be honest I would be surprised

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" contentType="text/html" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerText / textContent. 
Or create a text node with the styles, and add it to the style tag. 
It's not because the style is in the body, plus you can always add it to the head, which does not remedy the problem.