# How can I add a body element to an empty DOM document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this string that represents the body of a page, which I would like to parse for some elements. I believe (feel free to contradict me) the best way to do so is to create an empty document, then add the body and use standard JS methods to get what I want.
But I don't seem to be able to add the body to the document. In chrome, the following code fails on line 2 with `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7`.

```
 var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
 dom.firstChild.innerHTML = "<body><p>Hello world</p></body>";
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521698/chrome-error-with-no-modification-allowed-err-dom-exception-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to edit the innerHTML of the document's root element, but doing so of a child node is possible. So, this works:

```
    var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
    var body = dom.createElement("body");
    body.innerHTML = "<p>hello world</p>";
    dom.firstChild.appendChild(body);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in chrome 40.0.2214.93 m . I get a blank page if I put that in a script tag

Comment: I noticed that any content added on that body object wont' appear, but if you do setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML="something"},0) it does work

Answer (score 13):

As we are some years further than the originally accepted answer, I would like to give a more modern one.

In Firefox 50.0.2 you can do this:

```
document.body = document.createElement("body");
document.body.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
```

Here the body is created and directly assigned to "document.body".
Some reading (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-body-element-2) made me understand, that the document's attribute "body" can either be "null" or contain an object of type "body" or (not recommended) "frameset".

The following does **not** work, i.e. produces a blank page, because the assignment to "document.body" is missing:

```
var body = document.createElement("body");
body.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
```

Instead of `document.body = body;` you can do this:  `document.documentElement.appendChild(body);`, whereas `document.firstChild.appendChild(body);` throws an error ("HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy").

One might argue whether adding a paragraph by assessing innerHTML is the best way, but that's another story.

Comment: Brilliant, @JosefScript. I was trying various ways to get `document.appendChild(body);` and `document.append(body);` to work and I hadn't appreciated that it needed to be `document.documentElement.appendChild(body);`.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in recent versions of chrome, Antoine's answer doesn't work - you get a blank page. This, however, does work in chrome:

```
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
var body = dom.createElement("body");
dom.documentElement.appendChild(body);

// set timeout is needed because document.body is created after the current continuation finishes
setTimeout(function() {    
  document.body.innerHTML = "Hi"
},0)
```

Comment: @Mahi I don't know. Why not give it a try and report back here? : )

Comment: i think document is object and body is node so we cannot do ?

Comment: Well you won't have a document.body if there's no body on the page. That's the whole point of this question. I don't think I understand your confusion

Comment: good afternoon . i think we also cannot do `html.createElement`

Comment: why document can only creates element why cannot other elements can create element . ?

Comment: Because `.createElement()` is, explicitly, a method of `document`.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply write this code:

```
document.write('tagName Hello World tagName');
```